# css: vertical-align image with text inside span

Tags: html, css

Here a small demo of my issue...

```html
<html>

<body>
  <span style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCFF"> My text 
      <img style="width: 1em; height: 1em; vertical-align: middle;" 
      src="http://files.softicons.com/download/social-media-icons/stucco-social-media-icons-by-bradley-siefert/png/64x64/stucco-facebook.png"> My text </span>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see I have styled the image `vertical-align: middle` but still the image is misplaced at the bottom.

How do I get it centered between the top and bottom borders?

**EDIT:** Here's a good rundown of this issue:

http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I get it centered between the top and bottom borders?

You can try using the CSS [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Check the following example:

```css
span {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
img {
  width: 20px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
 <span style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCFF"> 
     My text 
   <img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/social-media-icons/stucco-social-media-icons-by-bradley-siefert/png/64x64/stucco-facebook.png"> 
   My text 
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks! In the end, this seems to me the simplest, general way to fix the code. Did not need to specify span.padding and img.margin, though -- the defaults work fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using `vertical-align: middle` adjust the image with the texts height, and as you can see in my screen-dump, the image is exactly between the text's top/bottom (I added 2 green lines to visualize it).

[image]

The "empty" space between the text and the top border, is how a particular font  (and this is different for different fonts) arranges the characters within its internal height.

Now, for what ever reason, if you want to "break" this and adjust for example an image within a fonts internal height (as in your question, between the top/bottom borders), you need to add "margin" somewhere.

To let the text flow as normal as possible, you could:

- add a few pixels margin/padding to the image element
- add a few extra lines of pixels with full transpareny on the image

Note: Based on how perfect you want this, you need to calculate the "margin" on the font you use (it can/will likely be different), the font size, and you also might want to check on different OS's as well.

To "force text/image" to center, you could:

- use `display: table` (work on IE8/9)
- use `display: flex`  (don't work on IE8/9)

Here is samples using "padding" and `display: table`:

```css
/* padding */
span img {
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  width: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* display table */
div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 5px;
}
div span {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
div img {
  width: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<span style="padding: 5px;border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCFF"> This one 
          <img 
          src="http://files.softicons.com/download/social-media-icons/stucco-social-media-icons-by-bradley-siefert/png/64x64/stucco-facebook.png"> use padding </span>

<br /><br />

<div style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCFF"> 
  <span>This one</span>
  <img src="http://files.softicons.com/download/social-media-icons/stucco-social-media-icons-by-bradley-siefert/png/64x64/stucco-facebook.png"> 
  <span>use display: table</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. --- What I find weird/inconsistent, though, is that vertical-align:top and vertical-align:bottom, both seems to align with the span-border as expected, while vertical-align:middle, actually puts the image one pixel LOWER than vertical-align:bottom --- I guess there was some committee somewhere pondering really hard for many years, to end up with such a specification :)

Comment: @Rop Yepp, found that also, updated my answer with a "for browsers that doesn't support flex" sample.

Answer (score 0):

As in this [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gj90vgh4/), I gave the wrapping `span` height value of `1.3em`, turned its display to `inline-block` so that the height value will take effect, then put a `margin-top:0.1em` for the image

```html
  <span style="display:inline-block;height:1.3em; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCFF"> My text 
  <img style="width: 1em; height: 1em; margin-top:.1em;" 
  src="http://files.softicons.com/download/social-media-icons/stucco-social-media-icons-by-bradley-siefert/png/64x64/stucco-facebook.png"> My text </span>
```

Note that you can set both the parent `span` and the `img` height to `1em` but keep the `display:inline-block;`, thusthe `img` will fit inside the span witouth margins.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
span
{
    display:inline-block;height:1.2em;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/9eufs9tf/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<html><body>
  <span style="border: 1px solid black; background-color: #CCCCFF"> My text 
  <img style="width: 1em; height: 1em; vertical-align: top; margin-top:1px" 
  src="http://files.softicons.com/download/social-media-icons/stucco-social-media-icons-by-bradley-siefert/png/64x64/stucco-facebook.png"> My text </span>
</body></html>`enter code here`
```

Comment: Please, add explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Give `padding-bottom` to your image

```
<img style="padding-bottom:2px; width: 1em; height: 1em; vertical-align: middle;" src="http://files.softicons.com/download/social-media-icons/stucco-social-media-icons-by-bradley-siefert/png/64x64/stucco-facebook.png">
```